# refer to a function in collection from view

Tags: backbone.js

How can I use a function in view when it is in collection ( how can I refer to it from another file) e.g. I have this pagination function in collection

```
pagination : function(perPage, page) {

                page = page - 1;
                var collection = this;
                collection = _(collection.rest(perPage * page));
                collection = _(collection.first(perPage));
                return collection.map( function(model) {
                    return model.toJSON();
                });
            },
```

Thats what I have tried in view but not correct:

```
var paginatedCollection = new BansCollection(pagination(this.pageSize,pageToLoad));
```

Answer (score 1):

It feels to me that a function that acts upon a collection should not be placed within a Backbone View object. 
I would put the pagination function in your BansCollection so you can do something like this in your view code:

```
var paginatedCollection = new BansCollection();
paginatedCollection.pagination(this.pageSize, pageToLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `initialize` your view you can also pass your collection with other options.

```
var myView = new MyView({collection: myCollection});
```

Then in your view you can reference to it using `this.collection`

As @JonasGeiregat suggests, view might not be a suitable place for pagination logic. So after you move your pagination logic to the collection you can do this within your view.

```
var models = this.collection.paginate(pageSize, page);
// render do whatever to print out those models/json
```